# Any keyboards that are just a bit wider/bigger?

Tags: keyboards

I have big hands, so am looking for a keyboard that is slightly bigger/spacious than normal. Apart from split mod keyboards, I cannot find anything. Recommendations for people with large hands?

Comment: I don't have super big hands (they fit on a Framework laptop, but just barely) and I like the Sharkoon Skiller SKG5. It's not super big but it's big enough for me (except when I try to put it in my backpack, then it's too big)